# Duplicate Push Notifications from Firebase Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, duplicates

I've been through the other threads on this issue and haven't found a solution. My case may be unusual.

I have just inherited a production mobile app (Ionic/Angular) that is available on Google Play Store and Apple App Store. I didn't have to create a new google-services.json or a new GoogleService-Info.plist file. I have access to the Firebase Console. I did have to replace the .p8 key for iOS in order to get APNs to play nicely.

I can send a single notification to a single FCM token for Android and iOS with no problem. But when our production system sends notifications they are often multiple duplicates. Additionally, we routinely send (for those subscribed) multiple but different notifications to the same device(s). For example, a user who is subscribed to topics A and B will normally get a single notification for each subscription. But right now, they'll get 3 of the same notification from A but only 1 from B (B, in this example, seems to behave normally). NOTE: the particular topic is irrlevant. The only thing that seems to matter in this case is that the first one will multiply and second is received only once.

Our server logs show only a single instance of sending any given notification despite multiples being received by devices.

I first suspected, and still do, that somehow during the "transition" of the project, somewhere in FB and Apple, there is a dangling reference to the original certs/keys/projects. I don't see how I can confirm/reject that idea. I also doubt it's the case. I need any and all suggestions because I'm out of ideas! Thanks in advance.